# Loop in Active Table Cell

Tags: vba, microsoft-word-2010

I am now working from the top of the Active Cell with this code:

```
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.TypeText Text:=", "
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
```

I need it to loop until the end of the active cell. Suggestions?

---

I'm trying to create a macro that takes a list of items and puts them all on the same line by separating them with commas and a space.

Example
1
2
3

to

1, 2, 3

Because each item is a different length I decided to work my way up from the bottom of the table. If there a way for me to loop the script to go up until the end of the content in the active table cell? I only want to apply it to the table cell I am working in.

The script I am trying to loop:

```
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.TypeBackspace
Selection.TypeText Text:=", "
```

Other suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just use the [Selection.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086(v=office.15).aspx) method.

This line will replace all spaces in the current selection with a comma + space:

> Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:=", "

Comment: Might it be that `a list` is *lines* of list items? Search and replace LF's .